# What are the types of data can be used with geoserver wps raw data implementation?

Tags: xml, multipartform-data, geoserver, raw, wps

In geoserver, we can create custom wps processes, I want to create a wps process which gets image and video data from client in multipart format. The geoserver wps post request needs body in xml format, how we can send image or video using this?

I wrote a wps process using raw data interface.

Comment: You can convert image to a Base64 string and include in a request.  Multipart attachments can be in raw format.  Each attachment starts on a line with two dashes.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)